# Php Mysql select column with an associative array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL column with associative arrays. I'd like to create a select query where `["xyz":"somevalue"]` below is how data is in the column :

```
{"abc":"0","xyz":"1"}
```

Comment: `json_encode` / `json_decode` ? I don't really understand what you're asking, but take a look at those functions

Comment: create the sql statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LIKE` to match it:

```
WHERE column LIKE '%"xyz":"somevalue"%'
```

It's a bad idea to store your data in JSON format like this if you need to be able to match it in queries. You should create an attribute table that contains each value as a separate row.

Comment: The data is store that way in the `joomla` ,thanks let me try this